# Create a keyboard shortcut to trigger time sync

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, date-time

I have a pretty old laptop and recently it's stopped keeping time unassisted (I know the cause but am too cheap to fix it when I'm already saving for a new laptop).

I've created a scheduled task to sync my clock every 15 minutes. This works great when I have the laptop up and running, no issues. The problem is when I wake it out of sleep mode; it's generally stopped keeping time and so doesn't know when the 15mins has passed to trigger the job.

I have to manually go in and sync the time by opening the date and time settings > internet time > change settings > update now. Then it'll then keep itself up to date properly until the next time I sleep it, when the process starts over again.

Can I somehow bind the time updating process to a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the famous AutoHotKey (AHK) to trigger your script. AHK has the ability to map arbitrary keystrokes to actions. You can find lots of examples, including ones very similar to what you're trying to do, in their [quick start tutorial](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm).
In short: Once the app is installed, save the following script as timeupdate.ahk, double click it, AHK launches, press Ctrl+j to resync your clock.

```
^j::
   Run w32tm /resync
Return
```

Usually, I recommend you to create a scheduled task that runs w32tm /resync (or whatever you use to sync your clock) every ~15 minutes on your computers. This is easier and works automatically. (This [site](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/auto-sync-pc-clock-on-windows-startup/) shows a similar approach with an external clock syncing tool: see 3rd point.) But this seems not to work for you.

Alternatively, you can also edit the update interval of the built in time sync service in the Windows registry:
Windows Registry Editor and navigate to the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet\Services \W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpClient
Select SpecialPollInterval.
```

Set the SpecialInterval value to your preferred update interval As Decimal in seconds.

Comment: The scheduled task is exactly what I do have running! The issue is once it's gone to sleep it stops tracking time and then doesn't re-start itself because 15 minutes never passes...until I manually kick it off again. In the mean time I'll check your solution when I'm back at that laptop.